# Display only the first 3 matching rows from a query via php PDO

Tags: php

this is for a homework assigment. I am suppose to: Demonstrate use of the SQL LIMIT clause by displaying only the first 3 matching rows from a query.

the "first 3 matching rows" part is throwing me off a bit. How do I match rows, or should I say find 3 matching rows. I know that in my table none of my rows 'match', its a simple table with 6 columns and 4 rows, I could add matching rows for demonstrating it.

I would be doing this using the PDO method via php obviously while using the sql limit statment to make it only 3 rows.

I figure a basis of the code would look something like this with a different sql statement.

**php**

```
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "";

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            // sql to delete a record
            $sql = "****select * from teams where 3 rows match****";

            // use exec() because no results are returned
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute()
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
            }

        $conn = null;
    }
```

Comment: use LIMIT 3 to fetch only 3 records

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "select * from teams [where condition(optional)] LIMIT 0,3";
```

where `0` means first row and `3` is number of rows you want

Refer http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Comment: wait so the select from teams "where 3 rows match" thats the correct sql statement? or should it be "SELECT * FROM teams LIMIT 0,3"?

Comment: `where` condition is optional, you can get matching records of count 3. If you don't pass any condition, it would fetch first 3 records. Updated Answer!

Answer (score 0):

Just use SQL [LIMIT](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php)

```
   $sql = "select * from teams LIMIT 3";
```

Comment: I guess i should have made myself a little clearer, I understand to use 'LIMIT" to limit the number of rows but the issue I have is with the 'MATCHING' rows statement in the instructions